# Update the link text

Tags: javascript, jquery

When clicking on the button first it will update just the text of the button and click on it the second time it will redirect to the URL.

Comment: Instead of using a standard anchor, you can use an `onclick` event to trigger a confirm dialog.  On success, you can redirect using window.location.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: Thanks for your comment i don't want to give a pop up instead i just want to change the text for confirm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)** to fire event handler only once

```js
// bind click event handler to fire once
$('#btn').one('click', function(e) {
  // prevent default click event action
  e.preventDefault();
  // change the tag text
  $(this).text('Confirm redirect')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="btn" href="template.html">Redirect</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```js
function confirm(ele) {
  if (ele.innerHTML === "Redirect")
    ele.innerHTML = "Confirm redirect";
  else
    location.href = "template.html";
}
```

```html
<a onclick="confirm(this)" >Redirect</a>
```